# Android app button for logging in (using Json)

Tags: java, android, json, android-button

I am making an app where users have to log in.

The problem is:
I enter right username and password, but first time I click the "login" button, it says: incorrect username/password. When I click it again, it says: succesfully logged in.

My question: Why do I have to click the button twice for logging in? I could not find it in the code

Here is the log:

```
12-04 08:57:26.113    1355-1474/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer E/JSON﹕ {"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"5480669c9f85b5.16469741","user":{"name":"lol","email":"username","created_at":"2014-12-04 14:50:20","updated_at":null}}
12-04 08:57:33.963    1355-1477/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer E/JSON﹕ {"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"5480669c9f85b5.16469741","user":{"name":"lol","email":"username","created_at":"2014-12-04 14:50:20","updated_at":null}}
12-04 08:57:33.983    1355-1479/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer E/JSON﹕ {"tag":"login","success":0,"error":1,"error_msg":"Incorrect email or password!"}
```

LoginActvitity.java:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnLinkToRegister;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView loginErrorMsg;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                Log.d("Button", "Login");
                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);


                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json != null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Succesfully login in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);
                            // Close Login Screen

                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in login
                            loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the UserFunctions.java:

```
public class UserFunctions {

    public JSONParser jsonParser;

    private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/";
    private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        JSONObject json;
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        // return json
        // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function get Login status
     * */
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        int count = db.getRowCount();
        if(count > 0){
            // user logged in
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Function to logout user
     * Reset Database
     * */
    public JSONObject logoutUser(Context context){
        JSONObject json;
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", null));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", null));
        json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return json;
    }

}
```

So the code works good, only that I have to click the login button twice.

1. Incorrect username/password (stays in LoginActivity.java)
2. Succesfully logged in (goes to DashboardActivity.java)

Any help is welcome

Comment: What happens when you click the first time, which logs are written, which code parts are executed? Which if() is true or fales? Which part of the if conditions if true/false?

Comment: When I click first time it says it executes:
loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
stays in loginactivity.java

and second time it executes:
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Succesfully login in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
And goes to dashboardactivity.java

Comment: So KEY_SUCCESS is not set to 1. But that's inside UserFunctions(), not listed here.

Comment: So first time I click, it goes in to the else part of the code

Second time I click it goes in into the if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1)

Comment: Well, I throw the Ring into the fires but still don't know what UserFunction.loginUser() does. Maybe you can post the code?

Comment: I added userfunctions.java

Comment: If you add `Log.e("JSON", json.toString());` right before `if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1)` and also log `res`, do they look like what you expect? The json should be the same as the log output of loginUser().

Comment: what do you mean with and also log res?

Comment: It crashes: unfortunately app has stopped

Comment: Content of `String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);`

Comment: The output of the JSON is correct. When I enter wrong entries, it says incorrect username/password. When I enter correct data, it says entries are correct. But it does not forward me automaticall to dashboardacvitity.java on first click.

Comment: So `Log.e("JSON", json.toString());` inside loginUserLogin() and `Log.e("JSON", json.toString());` before the if-line look the same? What about `Log.e("JSON", res+" -> "+Integer.parseInt(res));` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use asynctask while using network related tasks. Here what happens is , Whenever you press login it carries out network related task which takes some time. So at that instant the json respone is null or other value. So after sometime you have got your response , and when you click login, It works.  I hope this helps :)

```
 public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnLinkToRegister;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView loginErrorMsg;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                new ProcessLogin().execute();

            }
        });   


        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

        private class ProcessLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

            private ProgressDialog pDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
                pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
                pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);
                return json;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json != null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Succesfully login in",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                                    getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");                   

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME),
                                    json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),
                                    json.getString(KEY_UID),
                                    json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));

                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    DashboardActivity.class);

                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);
                            // Close Login Screen

                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                        else {
                            // Error in login
                            loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                        }
                }
                 catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }    
       } 

  }
```

Comment: Hmmm good point. I try to figure it out. Thanks for the help. Ill accept when I got it solved :-]

Comment: That's not correct. If userFunction.loginUser() is blocking then the result is in the same thread and is returned in the same call. But using ASyncTask for network operation is always a good idea.

Comment: Yes I heard about ASyncTask before, and that it should be applied on network operations. But first, I need to get this button issue solved :\

Comment: @brummfondel how are you sure that I am not correct. I really didnt get your point. I dont think they are on same thread.

Comment: @incr3dible noob see the code of loginUser(). If it would be async some kind of callback/event would be required. But it gives a json object as result.

Comment: Im giving it up man.. Ive been busy with this problem for like 4 hours. I tried everything, but I really cant solve it. Really really thanks for trying to help me

Comment: @muhammet Well have you tried my code.. I  had much similar code for login and i had also faced such problems. you are welcome :)

Comment: @brummfondel   http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.VIB__6b7sjg

Comment: @muhammet : My last try to make your job done, i have edited the code that i think  would fit exactly in ur code. I hope you know how to manage imports.

Comment: Yes I know that. I will try within couple of minute.  Thank you very much my friend

Comment: Sorry had some mistakes during copying so edited a bit again .. never been so desperate to solve issue :D

Comment: I have copied ur code. When entering wrong/correct entries it says Contacting Servers, Logging in. This method looks much better than what I done bymyself(thanks for that), but it does not respong on my first click on login button. I think I know whats wrong hold on

Comment: It works exactly like before. First time, it stucks and says it is logging in. I press 'back' and press login button, and he starts new activity. Maybe it is in other part of the code... Very weird